# HP Proliant ML350 CPU Turbo

Tags: windows-server-2016, xeon, hpe

I am unable to get my CPU to go into Turbo

ML350 with 1 x Xeon 4110, Windows Server 2016

Supposed turbo speed is 3ghz

I have the server set "Static High Performance Mode" from the iLo, and "High Performance" in windows

I run a 7z single core benchmark, set affinity to core 0, and inspect the CPU's speed with CPU-Z

The absolute highest the CPU will go is 2.4ghz

My laptop is faster

Can I hack out 3ghz from this server? It is essentially false advertising

Comment: Did you bother contacting HP support? This may be a bios issue.

Comment: It has been a behavior in the HP servers for a while now. I've seen 2620's run ok in a workstation, but experience serious throttling in servers.

Comment: Set BIOS to adaptive, check Core-Load and go to latest FPP. I had some clocking issues with silver xeons before, but everyon of my tickets was solved by client-configuration stuff. Short: It's not easy to clock it up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

"Static High Performance Mode" disables dynamic clock speeds, including turbo. Set to adaptive speed and you'll see single cores clocking up on load.

When all cores are running at the full, nominal speed there's no power/thermal budget to turbo. You need to have some cores clock down to allow other cores to take up the budget.

Comment: Are you able to confirm you reach more than 2.4ghz?

Comment: Did you reboot and set the Bios to adaptive?

Comment: I tried all sort, including the"Workload" profiles. I can't seem to get anywhere near the turbo i'd get on a desktop